# File monitoring using syslog

Tags: syslog, syslogd

Can rsyslog, syslog-ng programs monitor change of file? I want to monitor files and receive the changes made to the file by syslog on server. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have ssh-connection to your server you should try tail'ing it:

```
tail -f /file
```

Or using one line command:

```
ssh -n user@hostname1 'tail -f /your/log/file'
```

This will show which changes have been done to this file recently, for e.g., if some of your services/machines write something to your remote log.

Comment: Please explain how this works when the file is on a remote system (a server).